# Adding -es to adjectives after "etwas"

Tags: adjective, nominalization

*"traurig"* and other adjectives get an *-es* affix after "etwas" (e.g., *etwas trauriges*)

What are the conditions for this affixation? Does this have anything to do with case?

Comment: This has been answered before, see (http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/why-the-es-in-phrases-like-etwas-nasses).

Comment: @Uwe: in the question you linked to we have the case of nominalized adjectives, the question here is not covered by this (your answer says why). So as this Q here is admittedly very similar it is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: May be this is a related question (or the same) http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6489/rules-for-capitalizing-adjectives-after-etwas-nichts As for me, the OP is asking about the nominalization of adjectives.

Comment: @c.p. No, the question you linked is primarily: are the resulting words nouns and do they have to be capitalized?

Comment: @Uwe eigentlich nicht. The linked question already states that they are nouns: the question is why are they and whether every adjective can be substantivized that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, the -es ending of an adjective is the **indefinite neuter nominative** declination, e.g. ein schönes Wochenende, ein rotes Fahrrad, …

There are two more occasions where the -es ending is added to an adjective:

1)  The adjective is used as a noun (nominalised/substantiviert) and in the nominative case. Adjectives used as nouns always have the neuter gender. Remember: Nouns  must always be **capitalised**.

In sentence construction, 'etwas+noun' or the noun alone can be a *nominative subject* or a *nominative object*, e.g.

a) as a nominative object:

• Er sah **etwas Trauriges**. — He saw **something sad/saddening**.

• Zu Mittag aßen sie in der Kantine **Geschnetzeltes**. – For lunch they had Geschnetzeltes in the cafeteria. (Geschnetzeltes=meat cut into small stripes in a sauce, from adjective 'geschnetzelt' – cut into small stripes; actually, Geschnetzeltes has become a proper noun for this kind of dish.)

b) as a nominative subject:

• **Etwas Feuchtes** kroch ihr das Bein hinauf. – **Something wet** slithered its way up her leg (think Slither, the 2006 comedy horror film).

• **Hässliches** verkauft sich schlecht. – **Ugly things** don't sell well.

Now, what's the difference between 'etwas Hässliches' and 'Hässliches'? Same as in English: 'something ugly' versus 'ugly things in general'. Etwas/something is an *indefinite pronoun* here.

2) It's a different thing when 'etwas' is used as an *adverb* meaning 'a bit / a little / somewhat') to describe the adjective that itself describes a neuter noun in the nominative case:

• Es war **ein etwas unangenehmes Erlebnis**. – It was **a somewhat unpleasant experience**.

• Er gab **ein etwas trauriges Bild** ab. – He made **a bit of an awkward impression**.

(ein x Bild abgeben = colloquial expression for 'to look / make an impression / to appear' x.)

• Er machte **ein etwas trauriges Gesicht**. – He made **a somewhat sad face**.

Answer (score 3):

It's just the usual neuter form of the adjective <del>after an indefinite article</del>, the same as in "ein trauriges Kind". ("etwas" is neuter.)

Sorry, this was incorrect: it's the "no article" form, not the "indefinite article" form. The difference is only visible in the dative case ("einem traurigen" vs. "etwas traurigem").

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean nominative subject and accusative object? Because what you show in your example is an accusative object Er sah **etwas Trauriges**.