# Declension rules about adjectives after “keiner/keine/keines”?

Tags: declension, adjective-ending, indefinite-pronoun

I have viewed another question: [Adding -es to adjectives after “etwas”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6701/adding-es-to-adjectives-after-etwas)

But I am still uncertain how the indefinite pronouns keiner/keine/keines (no one, nobody) affect the adjective after it. And also jeder, niemand, jemand, alles…

Let's focus on keiner. Can I translate literally (maybe awkward):

- “No one broken was found.” as “Keiner kaputt wurde gefunden.”
- “I found no one broken.” as “Ich habe keinen kaputten gefunden”?

If not, how should the adjectives be inflected?

**UPDATE**

After some thoughts and reading some references, I think my real question is:

- Are there postpositive attributes in German?
- Do such phrases exist? like “not any one (house) that is *broken*” as “keines (von den Häusern) *kaputt*”.

Comment: *Broken* isn't an adjective in your examples but a participle in place of a relative clause. *No one **who was** broken was found. I found no one **who was** broken.* Please reconsider your question.

Comment: @Janka But isn't kaputt an adjective in German? Or maybe “no broken one” sounds more natural? (here “one” is any object except a person)

Comment: Yes, but you don't need an adjective to translate your sentences. German can go either with a participle or an adverb at that place: *Niemand/Keiner wurde kaputt aufgefunden.* See how *kaputt* isn't declined? That's because it's an adverb here. German makes adverbs from adjectives by not declining them.

Comment: @Janka Clever idiomatic sentence! My question looks pedantic. Then what about “I found no broken one (i.e. not any broken one)”?

Comment: @Janka Ah, another sentence is “Keiner wurde von mir kaputt aufgefunden.”, right? I'd like to see a “pedantic” answer about the right form of “keiner + adj”. Anyway, thank you a lot! :)

Comment: A *broken one* is *ein Kaputter/eine Kaputte/ein Kaputtes* in German. The participle/adjective turns into a noun, as so often in German, and also in this case.

Comment: As I have already written, *kaputt* isn't an adjective in your example, but an adverb. You can see this from the missing declination.

Comment: Please rephrase your question so it actually uses the participle/adjective as an adjective, as in *I found no broken person*. Not *one*, because that one is special.

Comment: @Janka Sorry my examples are misleading. :P I wonder whether a phrase like *keiner + adj.* exists or not, so I need to know how to decline that adjective. If not then I should stop here, since a better answer *kein Kaputter* has been found! Shall I answer my own question?

Comment: I think you misunderstand adjectives. They always precede a noun. If there is no noun, it's not an adjective. That's the same both in English and German.

Comment: Now you've changed the question completely. It would probably make more sense to to leave this one and ask a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kein** works exactly the same way as **ein** does:

> Das ist ein/kein gutes Beispiel
> Sie ist eine/keine schöne Frau
> Ich habe einen/keinen alten Mann gesehen
>
> etc.

You can find the details in any basic grammar book

**Keiner** is different and means *nobody*

> Keiner erklärt das so gut wie du

And there's also **keins**: *none*

> Es gibt noch keins <-> es gibt schon eins

UPDATE: since the question changed

No, German doesn't have postpositive attributes

Your example “not any one (house) that is broken” is not even good English. but you could maybe translate it as something like "Kein Haus, das kaputt ist"
or "Keines, das kaputt ist".
Better: "Kein kaputtes Haus"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all: I'm not really good at English, but I'll try ;)

So, in your question, there's already a mistake: 
It's not possible to have an adjective after "keiner" and "keines".

Example: "no apple" -> "kein Apfel" and not "keiner Apfel".
It's the same thing with neutrum-words

Example:

```
das Haus -> kein Haus
```

and NEVER keines Haus!!!!!

```
"Keiner" and "Keines" is ALWAYS used as a noun
```

Example:

```
Keiner kam zu meiner Party / Keines von den Häusern war gelb
```

(Nobody came to my party) / (None of the houses was yellow)

But the rest is easy :D

maskulin:
kein rot**er** Apfel

feminim:
keine schön**e** Frau

neutrum:
kein groß**es** Haus

I hope I could help you :)

Comment: (facepalm) Maybe my question is really misleading, but my reference to “etwas” is not unimportant at all. I'ved updated my question. I want to know whether there are postpositive attributes in German and whether there are phrases like “not any one (house) that is *broken*” exists as “keines (von den Häusern) *kaputt*”. And @Janka told me that it should be “kein Kaputtes”. Is that right?

Comment: Actually "keines" could be an adjective in the genitive: "Keines Hauses"